# How do I write a script to loop through SQL entries an insert values?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, for-loop

I have a table of people that is populated with all the MLB players (mostly contiguous by team), coaches and refs, as follows:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstname | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

as well as a players table, which is empty, but described as follows:

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| person_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| team_id   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I want to be able to loop through the players table and add in a range of person_ids and team_ids like this:

```
for(int x=100; x < 140; x++)
   insert into player values (NULL, x, 6)
```

but I know I can't mix and match languages like that, so how can I accomplish this? And if you need any further information just ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
insert into players( person_id, team_id ) as
select id, 6 
from my_first_table
where id >= 100
and id < 140
```